# Скопировать изображение в изображение

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pil

Необходимо скопировать изображение в изображение. Использую форк библиотеки pil для python3

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
mainPattern = Image.open(PatternPath)
main = Image.open(mainPatternPath)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(main)
draw.bitmap((5, 5), mainPattern)
main.save(OutPath + "name.jpg", "JPEG")
```

В итоге, изображение копируется(копирую png с прозрачным фоном), но оно абсолютно белое. Как скопировать изображение, сохранив цвета?

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось скопировать с учетом прозрачного фона после того как я добавил:

`main.alpha_composite(mainPattern, dest=(5, 5))`

Вот полный код:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

mainPattern = Image.open(PatternPath)
main = Image.open(mainPatternPath)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(main)
main.alpha_composite(mainPattern, dest=(5, 5))
main.save(OutPath + "name.png", "PNG")
```

---

Страница документации PIL по [*alpha_composite*](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.alpha_composite).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сменить строку:

```
main.save(OutPath + "name.jpg", "JPEG")
```

на:

```
main.save(OutPath + "name.jpg", "PNG")
```

Comment: Не помогло, напишу свою функцию